# Fastest way to remove duplicates from a vector<>

Tags: c++, vector, stl, duplicates

As the title says, I have in my mind some methods to do it but I don't know which is fastest.

So let's say that we have a: `vector<int> vals` with some values

**1**

After my `vals` are added

```
sort(vals.begin(), vals.end());
auto last = unique(vals.begin(), vals.end());
vals.erase(last, vals.end());
```

**2**

Convert to set after my `vals` are added:

```
set<int> s( vals.begin(), vals.end() );
vals.assign( s.begin(), s.end() );
```

**3**

When i add my `vals`, i check if it's already in my vector:

```
if( find(vals.begin(), vals.end(), myVal)!=vals.end() )
    // add my val
```

**4**

Use a set from start

Ok, I've got these 4 methods, my questions are:

1 From **1, 2** and **3** which is the fastest? 
2 Is **4** faster than the first 3? 
3 At **2** after converting the vector to set, it's more convenabile to use the set to do what I need to do or should I do the `vals.assign( .. )` and continue with my vector?

Comment: Well, did you measure?

Comment: Nope, I thought that somebody might know.

Comment: Ok @deepmax, you answered the second question, what about 1 and 3?

Comment: If the values are small enough, a bitmap is a _very_ fast solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question 1**: Both 1 and 2 are O(n log n), 3 is O(n^2). Between 1 and 2, it depends on the data.

**Question 2**: 4 is also O(n log n) and can be better than 1 and 2 if you have lots of duplicates, because it only stores one copy of each. Imagine a million values that are all equal.

**Question 3**: Well, that really depends on what you need to do.

The only thing that can be said without knowing more is that your alternative number 3 is asymptotically worse than the others.

If you're using C++11 and don't need ordering, you can use `std::unordered_set`, which is a hash table and can be significantly faster than `std::set`.

Comment: `unordered_set` is a very good suggestion, and pre C++11 can be found in the `boost` library and often as a compiler extension.  The more repeats of the same values there are in the input, the more benefit you derive from eliminating the duplicates earlier.

Comment: You have enough karma now ;-). This is a good answer, particularly the last point. Plus one.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 is going to beat all the others. The complexity is just O(N log N) and the contiguous memory of vector keeps the constant factors low.

std::set typically suffers a lot from non-contiguous allocations. It's not just slow to access those, just creating them takes significant time as well.

Comment: On review, I like this answer, plus one. Although I need to study `std::unique`. I will not take it personally if you downvote mine ;-)

Comment: Plus those nodes are comparatively pretty expensive memory-wise as well when your element is an `int` :)

Answer (score 1):

These methods all have their shortcomings although (1) is worth looking at.

But, take a look at this 5th option: Bear in mind that you can access the vector's data buffer using the `data()` function. Then, bearing in mind that no reallocation will take place since the vector will only ever get smaller, apply the algorithm that you learn at school:

```
unduplicate(vals.data(), vals.size());

void unduplicate(int* arr, std::size_t length) /*Reference: Gang of Four, I think*/
{
    int *it, *end = arr + length - 1;
    for (it = arr + 1; arr < end; arr++, it = arr + 1){
        while (it <= end){
            if (*it == *arr){
                *it = *end--;
            } else {
                ++it;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And resize the vector at the end if that is what's required. This is never worse than O(N^2), so is superior to insertion-sort or sort then remove approaches.

Your 4th option might be an idea if you can adopt it. Profile the performance. Otherwise use my algorithm from the 1960s.

Comment: I believe the OP has flags `c++`,`vector`,`stl` so accessing the internal buffer could be inappropriate. Better yet if you access the internal buffer, personally, I would not use `c++`,`vector`,`stl` would I?

Comment: Since C++03 when the `vector` data is guaranteed by the standard to be contiguous, there's nothing wrong with accessing the internal buffer, so long as you know what you're doing. I've already asserted that no reallocation will occur. If performance matters (as would appear in this case), accessing the data buffer is permissible.

Comment: I agree with KiaMorot, there appears to be no reason to use pointers here. In fact, the name `it` already hints at iterators. And in fact the algorithm uses just bidirectional access. That BTW also explains why it's so inefficient. `std::sort` followed by `std::unique` is O(N log N) not O(N*N).

Comment: Naturally, I take the opposite position. Perhaps that's down to my using C-style algorithms in my day job, so am used to "connecting" them with C++ standard library containers. I'd always shy away from recoding an algorithm from scratch. This all set, using `std::set` throughout if possible, is the way to go in this instance.

Comment: @Bathsheba: There's a bit of irony; "shy away from recoding an algorithm from scratch" and then recode an algorithm which is worse than the existing C++ Standard Library algorithms..

Comment: BTW, while we're at it, how does the caller get the result? There's no return value or out parameter.

Comment: Vector is modified "in place". You can always resize using `end`.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I don't understand how a worst case `O(N²)` **is** (and not may be) superior to `O(N log N)`...

Comment: Although (4) is O(N log N), each operation is considerably more expensive. All this said, the OP would be well-advised to accept option (1), and "race the horses" in any instance.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem recently, and experimented with **1**, **2**, and **4**, as well as with `unordered_set` version of **4**. In turned out that the best performance was the latter one, **4** with `unordered_set` in place of `set`.

BTW, that empirical finding is not too surprising if one considers that both `set` and `sort` were a bit of overkill: they guaranteed relative order of unequal elements. For example inputs `4,3,5,2,4,3` would lead to **sorted** output of unique values `2,3,4,5`. This is unnecessary if you can live with unique values in arbitrary order, i.e. `3,4,2,5`. When you use `unordered_set` it doesn't guarantee the order, only uniqueness, and therefore it doesn't have to perform the additional work of ensuring the order of different elements.